# Address input in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want a simple thing.
When the user puts his address in the box I want that in the 2nd activity, after I press "show address" it will open google map with the user input address and not "geo" address

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btSand == v) {
            AdressLoc = etAdress.getText().toString();

            SendMail = etMail.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",etName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Mail",etMail.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[first activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FND7Z.png)

```
else if (btnAdress == v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:31.59,34.55"));
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Map");
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31ALg.png)

Comment: You might want to check the [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to get the address using the lat/long. Here is a related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32116202/5995040) that uses the geocoder to translate a lat/long value to an address. You can use the input of the user in the [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) if you don't want to use the return value of the geo address. Hope this helps.

Comment: no its not help becuz im using somthing more simple i just want the user input like intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + userInput));